# Where does xorg.conf find its video drivers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, xorg.conf

I have the following section in xorg.conf

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Default Device"
    Driver  "fglrx"
EndSection
```

In what directory does it look to find the fglrx driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the xorg-xserver searche for its drivers in:

```
/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers
```

with installed 'fglrx' you can find a symlink called `fglrx_drv.so` which points (essentially) to `/usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so`. you can find out the name of the package providing that file by

```
% dpkg -S /usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
```

which should result in `fglrx`. you can find out the rest of the files belonging to that package with:

```
% dpkg -L fglrx
```